# Understanding a phrase - 必ずやらなければならないことを　まとめてみた

Tags: grammar, set-phrases

I am trying to understand what looks like an expression, but seems too verbose. And I'm confused by the use of まとめてみた. To put it into context, the title of this page in my guide book is ひとめでわかる　攻略チャート　(Understanding the strategy chart at a glance).

> 冒険を進めるために、必ずやらなければならないことを　まとめてみた。
>
> In order to continue the adventure, if you definitely do the thing you have to do altogether try (???)

This is from

> やらなければ　ならないことをする - do what one needs to do;
>
> and
>
> まとめて – in one go; all at once; altogether

The final part dsoesn't seem to make sense. It's as if まとめてみた is not needed.

Comment: まとめる = to summarize, organize (into a chart, in this case) :-)<br>
BTW I'm curious where your "if you" came from...

Comment: やらなければ but I think I am wrong...

Comment: Oh I see! ～なければいけない/～なければならない = "have to, must"; try memorizing this as a whole. Good luck!

Comment: Ah I remember a phrase 行けなければなりません - I must go. This is the same isn't it?

Comment: Of course it is!

Comment: No, it is 行か, not 行け.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because translating a whole sentence is prohibited here (in what I understand), instead I will leave some fragments of words below. So, please try putting them together into a sentence.

> ～てみる = try to ～ / start by ～ing
>   まとめる = to summarize
>   こと = things
>   ～なければならない = have to / must
>   やる = to do (almost equivalent to する)
>   [必]{かなら}ず = invariably / without question

Comment: I think translating the whole sentence is fine if the answerer wants to, as long as there is *also* an effort to break things down, so it isn't completely opaque what happened.

Comment: I'm gonna mark this as the answer, partly because of your help earlier (in the comments).

Comment: @DariusJahandarie - I think you are right and your words helped me understand it better. Thank you very much!

Comment: @VictorySaber - I'm glad if it helped. I recommend you to learn elementary basics (of vocabs and grammar) intensively, it will improve your skill by much, rapidly. So, good luck in your learning!

Comment: まとめる in this context is much closer to "make a list" than to "summarize".

Comment: Or "make a chart" like I said, guessing from the title of the book. Anyway, I thought at least "summarize" was not a mistranlation, and would be more versatile (than any more specific meanings) when memorized. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question, you just don't know usage of `~~してみた` .

`~~してみた` is very popular on internet recently, you could find `ダンスしてみた`, `歌ってみた`.
this form can be converted into `した`, so `まとめてみた` is simply `まとめた`, *summarized*.

`してみた` makes past verb and also has nuance of *tried to do*, but personally I think the nuance is "tried, but less effort. actually i enjoyed." hmm I hope this answers your question.